# EnumPath with CaseBuilder (QueryDSL 3.6.2)

Tags: mysql, querydsl

I have a problem using the `CASE WHEN THEN` with `EnumPath`

```
Expression<CampaignStatus> cases = new CaseBuilder().when(qCampaign.campaignStatus.gt(CampaignStatus.NOT_SENT)).then(CampaignStatus.ERROR);
```

(CampaignStatus is Enum)

and I want to eventually use this Case in an request update

```
EnumExpression<CampaignStatus> cases = new CaseBuilder().when(qCampaign.campaignStatus.eq(CampaignStatus.SENT)).then(CampaignStatus.ERROR).otherwise(CampaignStatus.ERROR);
            new JPAUpdateClause(manager, qCampaign)
                    .set(qCampaign.campaignStatus, cases)
                    .where(qCampaign.id.eq(campaignId))
                    .execute();
```

QClass:

```
 @Generated("com.mysema.query.codegen.EntitySerializer")
public class QCampaign extends EntityPathBase<Campaign> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1869070992L;

    private static final PathInits INITS = PathInits.DIRECT2;

    public static final QCampaign campaign = new QCampaign("campaign");

    public final StringPath address = createString("address");

    public final StringPath application = createString("application");

    public final StringPath applicationId = createString("applicationId");

    public final SetPath<CampaignFleet, QCampaignFleet> campaignFleet = this.<CampaignFleet, QCampaignFleet>createSet("campaignFleet", CampaignFleet.class, QCampaignFleet.class, PathInits.DIRECT2);

    public final EnumPath<net.atos.tum.rcs.rmessage.core.enums.CampaignStatus> campaignStatus = createEnum("campaignStatus", net.atos.tum.rcs.rmessage.core.enums.CampaignStatus.class);

    public final SetPath<CampaignVehicle, QCampaignVehicle> campaignVehicle = this.<CampaignVehicle, QCampaignVehicle>createSet("campaignVehicle", CampaignVehicle.class, QCampaignVehicle.class, PathInits.DIRECT2);

    public final DateTimePath<java.util.Date> createDate = createDateTime("createDate", java.util.Date.class);

    public final QDisplayMethod displayMethod;

    public final StringPath gpsCoords = createString("gpsCoords");

    public final BooleanPath html = createBoolean("html");

    public final NumberPath<Long> id = createNumber("id", Long.class);

    public final StringPath phoneNumber = createString("phoneNumber");

    public final BooleanPath pro = createBoolean("pro");

    public final StringPath progress = createString("progress");

    public final SetPath<PushConfig, QPushConfig> pushConfigs = this.<PushConfig, QPushConfig>createSet("pushConfigs", PushConfig.class, QPushConfig.class, PathInits.DIRECT2);

    public final DateTimePath<java.util.Date> sendingDate = createDateTime("sendingDate", java.util.Date.class);

    public final SetPath<TemplateMessage, QTemplateMessage> templateMessages = this.<TemplateMessage, QTemplateMessage>createSet("templateMessages", TemplateMessage.class, QTemplateMessage.class, PathInits.DIRECT2);

    public final BooleanPath temporary = createBoolean("temporary");

    public final StringPath title = createString("title");

    public final QUser user;

    public QCampaign(String variable) {
        this(Campaign.class, forVariable(variable), INITS);
    }

    public QCampaign(Path<? extends Campaign> path) {
        this(path.getType(), path.getMetadata(), path.getMetadata().isRoot() ? INITS : PathInits.DEFAULT);
    }

    public QCampaign(PathMetadata<?> metadata) {
        this(metadata, metadata.isRoot() ? INITS : PathInits.DEFAULT);
    }

    public QCampaign(PathMetadata<?> metadata, PathInits inits) {
        this(Campaign.class, metadata, inits);
    }

    public QCampaign(Class<? extends Campaign> type, PathMetadata<?> metadata, PathInits inits) {
        super(type, metadata, inits);
        this.displayMethod = inits.isInitialized("displayMethod") ? new QDisplayMethod(forProperty("displayMethod")) : null;
        this.user = inits.isInitialized("user") ? new QUser(forProperty("user"), inits.get("user")) : null;
    }

}
```

Exception:

```
10:41:50.436 [qtp1497627503-24] ERROR [] NewCampaign               Render queue error in SetupRender[NewCampaign]: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.JavaConstantNode cannot be cast to org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectExpression 
org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.TapestryException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.JavaConstantNode cannot be cast to org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectExpression
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$AbstractPhase.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:158) ~[tapestry-core-5.3.7.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$SetupRenderPhase.render(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:186) ~[tapestry-core-5.3.7.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RenderQueueImpl.run(RenderQueueImpl.java:72) [tapestry-core-5.3.7.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageRenderQueueImpl.render(PageRenderQueueImpl.java:124) [tapestry-core-5.3.7.jar:?]
    at $PageRenderQueue_53dac9603a07.render(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at $PageRenderQueue_53dac96039e5.render(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.MarkupRendererTerminator.renderMarkup(MarkupRendererTerminator.java:37) [tapestry-core-5.3.7.jar:?]
    at org.got5.tapestry5.jquery.services.js.JSModule$1.renderMarkup(JSModule.java:44) [tapestry5-jquery-3.4.0.jar:?]
```

Comment: What's the problem? Can you post your Q class too please?

Comment: Yes, what is the problem here?

Comment: I would like to make an update is used CaseBuilder: Expression<CampaignStatus> cases = new CaseBuilder().when(qCampaign.campaignStatus.gt(CampaignStatus.NOT_SENT)).then(CampaignStatus.ERROR);    -->       .set(qCampaign.campaignStatus, cases)

Comment: I get the above exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution :

```
EnumExpression<CampaignVehicleStatusEnum> cases = new CaseBuilder()
                .when(qCampaignVehicle.status.eq(CampaignVehicleStatusEnum.TO_SAVE))
                    .then(EnumTemplate.create(CampaignVehicleStatusEnum.class, String.valueOf(CampaignVehicleStatusEnum.OK.getStatus())))
                    .otherwise(EnumTemplate.create(CampaignVehicleStatusEnum.class, String.valueOf(CampaignVehicleStatusEnum.ERROR.getStatus())));
```

The request update:

```
new JPAUpdateClause(manager, qCampaignVehicle)
                .set(qCampaignVehicle.status, cases)
                .where(qCampaignVehicle.pk.campaign.id.eq(campaignId))
                .where(qCampaignVehicle.pk.vehicle.id.in(listOfVehicleId))
                .where(qCampaignVehicle.status.eq(CampaignVehicleStatusEnum.TO_SAVE)
                        .or(qCampaignVehicle.status.eq(CampaignVehicleStatusEnum.ERROR_TO_SAVE)))
                .execute();
```